# Angular 8: Listen to inner element that is in the unaccessible component

Tags: angular, dom, listen

I installed MuiOrgChartModule to show my nested data as a tree view and i only have access to whole element like this:

```
<mui-org-chart #chart (itemClick)='showOuManagementDialog($event)' [topEmployee]="displayOuResult" direction="vertical"></mui-org-chart>
```

but i want to access inner element of "mui-org-chart" for customize each node of my tree 
how can i do this?

can you help me?

Comment: You can use [topEmployee]  directive to to pass employee hierarchy. So you can change employee details in your displayOuResult in your ts file.

Comment: @hackerbuddy I want to change my DOM not change my data

Answer (score 0):

using

```
::ng-deep {
  // your scss file goes here for children 
}
```

or this approch which is not good practice

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```